# Need to update network driver each time I start Windows 8.1 to get internet connection

Tags: wireless-networking, drivers

After having upgraded to Windows 8.1, my **Intel(R) PRO/Wireless 3945ABG Network Connection** fails to get internet connection each time I start Windows. A workaround is this:

1. Click on **Update driver** in Device Manager
2. Click on **Browse my computer for driver software**
3. Click on **Let me pick from a list of device drivers on my computer**
4. In the list of Network drivers, select the network card and click **Next**.

After that, the network card connects to the WLAN.

What is the reason for this? How can I fix this?

Comment: The first step is to remove both adapater.  After you remove both adapaters and their drivers use Device Manager to install the Windows 8.1 drivers

Comment: Ok, I have updated my question. After removing the unit in Device Manager there is now only one network card in the list in step 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution:

1. Right-click the wireless NIC in Device Manager and click **Properties**.
2. Open the **Power management** tab and uncheck **Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power**.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by selecting Maximum Performance in the Power Options->Advanced Settings->Wireless Adapter Settings and unchecking the "Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power" setting in the Power Management tab for the Wireless Adapter in Device Manager.

All will be fine after this.

Answer (score 0):

actually both solutions are required:
Open the Power management tab and selecting Maximum Performance in the Power Options.

with those 2 points issue is solved.

also will be helpful to update version 13.3 to 13.4 here is the link:
http://www.driverscape.com/download/intel%28r%29-pro-wireless-3945abg-network-connection

specifically version 13.3 has an issue with power saving features.
i am working with a toshiba laptop 7 years old and the driver is always an issue with every sistem update, now i am with win10.

regards